# Local notification on cordova 3.5.0 aren't working?

Tags: javascript, ios, cordova, localnotification

I used to add the https://github.com/katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications plugin in order to get local notification on my apps, but since the version 3.5.0 the plugin is not loaded anymore by cordova...

The plugin seems correctly added, since I can see it in the : `cordova plugin list` result

In the JS code I got

```
if(window.plugin && window.plugin.notification){
            window.plugin.notification.local.add({ message: 'a msg' }); 
        }
```

but window. plugin is undefined.

Am I missing something or something changed with the version 3.5.0?

Answer (score 2):

The plugin will be available once the "Device is Ready". Listen the device ready event and then call you alert function.

https://github.com/jonbarlo/cordova-plugin-local-notifications#using-the-plugin

```
document.addEventListener('deviceready', function () {
   // window.plugin.notification.local is now available
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a surprise here.
Whenever you enable a plugin, you have to download the debugger again, and install on the virtual machine / device for it to recognize the plugin.
The docs didn't say it. I've just discovered it today.